# GIT SVN clone a specifc directiory

Tags: git, svn, version-control, git-svn

We are using a non standard layout for our projects in SVN.

http://svn_root/Path/ABC/development contains multiple folders. The folders are either an application folder or a library folder. SVN repo contains multiple actual projects as subdirectories

Im trying to clone a single folder under development folder to a dedicated repo in GIT.

SVN folder structure is

```
SVN_ROOT/
    ABC/
       development/
             Project1/
                     files
             Library1/
                     files
             Project2/
                     files
```

So when i run the `git svn clone` im trying to achieve this folder structure

```
GIT_Repo/
        .git
        Project1/
              files
```

It is important that the files remain in the Project1 folder

I tried the following commands and several such variants

```
git svn clone http://SVN_ROOT/ABC/development/Project1 GitRepo
git svn clone --trunk=/ABC/development/Project1 http://SVN_ROOT/ GITRepo
```

All the commands end up with the same folder structure

```
GITRepo/
     files
```

The command is unable to retain the project folder and placing the project files directly in the GIT Repo.

Answer (score 3):

You can use below command to clone, and it will make the git repo structure as `root/Project1/files`:

```
git svn clone http://SVN_ROOT/ABC/development --include-paths Project1
```

---

If you want to remove the unnecessary commits (for the changes out of Project1 folder), you can clone the url for http://SVN_ROOT/ABC/development/Project1, and then create Project1 folder and move files into it:

```
git svn clone http://SVN_ROOT/ABC/development/Project1 Gitrepo
cd Gitrepo
mkdir Project1
mv * Project1
git add .
git commit -m 'move files into Project1/files'
```

Comment: this trick works but this is creating a ton of unnecessary commits before the first actual commit for Project1 shows up in the log history. Anyway to avoid it??

Comment: The command will truly migrate the commits out of `Project1`. If you want to skip unnecessary commits, you can refer the alternative way which I added  in the end of my answer, you can have a try.

Comment: But what if I need to clone Project1 and Project2 into Gitrepo and want to remove unnecessary commits? `git svn clone http://SVN_ROOT/ABC/development --include-paths 'Project1|Project2'` will produce unnecessary commits.

Answer (score 0):

Make a folder called GITRepo.
Inside that folder run

```
git svn clone http://SVN_ROOT/ABC/development/Project1
```

If you wanted all of the projects and libraries,

```
git svn clone http://SVN_ROOT/ABC/development GitRepo
```

When you run `git svn clone http://SVN_ROOT/ABC/development/Project1 GitRepo`, you will get a folder called GitRepo with all of the files/folders starting in Project1.

Edit:

Create the folder GIT_Repo
Inside that folder run

```
git svn init http://SVN_ROOT/ABC/development
```

Open .git/config. It should be something like

```
[svn-remote "svn"]
    url = http://SVN_ROOT/ABC
    fetch = development/Project1:refs/remotes
```

Then run `git svn fetch`

Comment: Hi Ben, I do not want all my projects in a single repo. Since every folder under the development folder is either an application or a library, I have to create a git repo for every folder.